# React Native Swiper Custom

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, swipe

Is there an easy way to implement infinite fullscreen swipe up/down function (by pulling json data from the database) as well as swipe left/right?

On swipe down I need to change the screen according to the database entry - 10 items initially loaded and when reaching the last one, next 10 loaded from remote mysql database. On each screen there should be swipe right/left option to display details about the individual item.

I was thinking to use FlingGestureHandler https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/api/gesture-handlers/fling-gh/.
I am however not sure how to combine it with swipe left/right/up/down animation.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? Yes, you can implement an infinite scroll with the ability to swipe left and and right.

Comment: Thanks! 1. How to implement infinite scroll reload from DB after 10 screens/pictures? 2. How to combine it with swipe/left/up/down animation? 3. Use fling-gh or any other library?

Comment: I am not sure how well it handles left/right swipes, but I think a `FlatList` or a `ScrollView` is a good place to start